# Kill First Form and Start New One

Tags: c#, winforms

Okay I've seen a few similar questions to this, but I'm not sure how exactly to address the issue. Basically I am working on creating a game in C# and the first form asks the user if they would like to start a new game or resume a previous one. When the user hits "New Game" for example, I want to close out this form and start a new one where this form would be the actual game. While of course these are different platforms & languages, I can do this in Android easily by killing the first Activity and going to another Activity. In C# if I attempt to kill the first form the entire program terminates because the process has ended!

I would think there has to be a better solution to this problem than keeping the first form active and hiding it? It seems wasteful to me to hide it at least. Any ideas would be highly appreciated!!! Thank you for your time in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, hiding it can be considered 'wasteful'. But that's one of the main differences between mobile and desktop: you rarely have to worry about resources in that way on a desktop. You really have three options:

1. Hide the form using some method (`Hide()` or `Visible=false` for example)
2. You can always redraw content on your main form instead of hiding it. Creating a UserControl or using a Panel would probably be the easiest way.
3. Use a [Multiple Document Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where the form you want to get rid of is really a child form of the main application form.

Comment: This is true, the resources on a PC isn't something to sweat about usually. I just always try not to waste anything if I can help it!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways

1) You can Hide Form

```
Form f1=new Form();
f1.Hide();
```

2) Make it visible False

```
Form f1=new Form();
f1.Visible=False;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it does *not* destroy the instance when hidden or not visible...

Comment: DresJordan is correct. Specifically: `Close` will destroy the form (meaning it will `Dispose` the `Form`), `Hide` will not

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach.  Make your "game" form the main one which is brought up immediately.  Then in that form's Load event you hide the form and bring up your form asking whether you want a new or old game.

After they answer the question you close the secondary form and use the Boolean answer to decide what information to load into the form.  Then show the game form.

```
    private void GameForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        using (frmAsk frm = new frmAsk())
        {
            frm.ShowDialog();
            LoadGameInfo(frm.LoadNewGame);
        }
        this.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your shutdown mode to close when the last form closes instead of the main form.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hzfysdc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Additionally, I would suggest if you're just learning .NET/WinForms to learn WPF instead, especially for a game. WPF allows you to set shutdown mode to "explicit", ie when you say so.

Edit: I just re-read that link, and it says it only works for VB projects.

There's nothing wrong with your approach of  running a main form in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it.  In your Program class, create a public static property that keeps re-creating the main form.

```
static class Program
{
    public static bool KeepRepeating = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        do 
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        } while (KeepRepeating);
    }
}
```

Then if you want your form to be re-created after closing, just set the property to true and close your main form:

```
            Program.KeepRepeating = true;
            this.Close();
```

Just to be cautious, you could set your repeating property to false right after you instantiate the form so that if the form is abnormally terminated due to an exception you won't get stuck in an endless loop:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        Program.KeepRepeating = false;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just "kill" a container (i.e. panel) holding your menu inside your first form and setting up annother one inside holding your game?